# ¿Cómo vuelvo a mostrar las ventanas y menú en visual studio code?

Tags: html

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se qué se hace. Ya lo intente todo .

Comment: ¿Ya has presionado la tecla `alt` del teclado?

Comment: Creo que solo esta en modo presentacion presiona `F11` y listo

Comment: SI YO INGRESE PRESIONANDO ALT + E Y SALIO EL MENU

Answer (score 2):

Presiona ALT + E, y después teclea:

>Toggle Menu Bar y da *Enter*.

Comment: En mi caso para abrir la consola en vez de ALT+E, es F1

Answer (score 1):

si, con alt me apareció el menú de nuevo después le di ahí y me salio esa opción para mostrar la barra derecha[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score -1):

Reinicialo y vuelve a presionar <kbd>ALT</kbd>